# Check if user facebook ID and session from mobile client are real?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a mobile app, and the user can sign in using facebook. So on the client, I'll get their facebookId, and a session token.

Now I want to send the facebook ID up to my server to link to their account. But I want to verify that the ID is trusted - if I also send the session token from the client to the server, is there a facebook API which will let me verify that a facebook ID + session token is real?

Example of the client talking to my server:

```
https://example.com/myservice/getMyAppAccountInfo?fbId=123&fbSessionToken=abc
```

now on my server, can I ask facebook if the ID and session token are correct? I don't want a malicious user just grabbing someone's facebook ID then impersonating them.

Thanks

Comment: Usually you should use the `signed_request` parameter for that – it’s signed with your app secret, so if that checks out, the request is genuine.

Comment: Oh no that's my client going to my server. But now the server needs to know if the supplied facebook ID + session token are valid.

Comment: Don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: The client gets a facebook ID and a facebook session token itself. I want to send those up to my server. But my server has no way of knowing if those values are valid (could be a malicious user impersonating my client). So the server-side needs a way to verify if the supplied facebook ID and facebook session token match.

Comment: _How_ does the client get this? Don’t the login within your app? How does login happen? (Do you mean a mobile app or a native app?)

Comment: It's a mobile app. The mobile app uses the fb sdk to get a facebook session token and the user ID. Then it sends it up to my server. But the server should check if that ID + token are real. I'm wondering how to do that check.

Comment: The JS SDK? If so, that delivers `signed_request` as part of the FB.login response.

Comment: No, the android sdk. The real issue is the app server shouldn't blindly trust input from the client (even though they're mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I ended up calling this server-side, using the facebook session token supplied by my client:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=tokenSuppliedByMyClient
```

if the access_token is real, then you'll get a json response that is the facebook user object associated with that session token:

```
// the facebook user object associated with the session token:
{
  "id": "123", 
  "name": "...",
  ...
}
```

then I compare the "id" attribute in the json to the facebook ID supplied by the client. If everything matches up at this point, I'll trust the client.